# adding values in a 2d array provided that the first value is greater than 5

Tags: python, arrays

there is such question, it seems elementary, but for some reason at me it does not turn out. I have the 2 d list, I need to add a line to a line so that the sum on the first number was not less than 5 (it is possible to sum up only the next lines). For example

```
array([[  0.      ,   3.817549],
       [  3.      ,  21.275711],
       [ 11.      ,  59.286198],
       [ 47.      , 110.136649],
       [132.      , 153.451585],
       [263.      , 171.041259],
       [301.      , 158.872652],
       [198.      , 126.488376],
       [ 50.      , 200.63002 ]])
```

and I need outpuut like this:

```
array([[  14.      ,   84.3794...],
       [ 47.      , 110.136649],
       [132.      , 153.451585],
       [263.      , 171.041259],
       [301.      , 158.872652],
       [198.      , 126.488376],
       [ 50.      , 200.63002 ]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
arr = np.array([[  0.      ,   3.817549],
               [  3.      ,  21.275711],
               [ 11.      ,  59.286198],
               [ 47.      , 110.136649],
               [132.      , 153.451585],
               [263.      , 171.041259],
               [301.      , 158.872652],
               [198.      , 126.488376],
               [ 50.      , 200.63002 ]])

for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i, 0] >= 5.0:
        arr = arr[i:, :]
        break
    else:
        arr[i + 1, :] += arr[i, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand the question, but I will try to help.

I would approach this problem with the following steps:

1. Create a separate 2D list to store your final output and a two-value accumulator list to temporary store values. Initialize the accumulator to the values at index [0][] of your input array
2. Iterate over the values in the original 2D list
3. For each item:

   a. if accumulator[0] >= 5, add the accumulated values to your output and then set the accumulator to the values at current_index + 1

   b. otherwise, *add* the values at current_index + 1 to your accumulator

The following code was able to take your input and reproduce the exact ouput you wanted:

```py
# Assuming current_vals is the input list...
  final_vals = []
  accumulator = [current_vals[0][0], current_vals[0][1]]

  for sublist_index in range(1, len(current_vals) - 1):
    if accumulator[0] >= 5:
      final_vals.append([accumulator[0], accumulator[1]])
      accumulator[0] = current_vals[sublist_index][0]
      accumulator[1] = current_vals[sublist_index][1]
    
    else:
      accumulator[0] += current_vals[sublist_index][0]
      accumulator[1] += current_vals[sublist_index][1]

  return final_vals
```

Comment: Important thing to note is that I did not test this with the trailing decimal for your 0th index values in the sublists. Not sure if that changes anything. But this does work fine.

Comment: sorry. i don't know . why it is not working